# Extract images from RTF

Tags: image, rtf

I need to extract `images` from `RTF` format on OSX. (NSAttributedStrings does not do this) I trying to do this with `regexp` (I dont know better way). But as I understood `RTF` is too hard to `regexp` parsing. Help me please, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

The [RTF 1.9.1 spec](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10725) has an entire section on how to decode an image embedded in an .rtf file. In general, you can't use regexp to parse structured data that requires nesting or recursion to parse. However, since images are embedded as `{\pict ... }` and don't nest, you might be able to simply match that expression to find all the images.

Comment: Upvoting for the link to the RTF spec.

Comment: You are right. But {\pict } block also can have others embedded blocks {}. And I don't have large experience with regexps for writing regexp for my needs. In my task - I just need replace pict blocks with other blocks - that is all. Writing own RTF parser - I think not better idea. Because I think it should be great open source parsers.